# Dual boot Debian & Windows 10 - extending partition after cloning on larger disk

Tags: debian, partition, windows, dual-boot, move-partition

I'm messing around for a week and I'm stuck right now.

I had a 128gb SSD with Windows10 (partition 1,2) and Debian (partition 3,4) running on dual boot

[image: disk manager original 128gb disk]

I needed more space however. So I cloned the disk on a 1tb SSD. Which works perfect. Now I have quite some 700gb unallocated space at the end:

[image: new cloned disk with 1tb]

view from gparted:

[image]

What I need is to get the Windows partition extended by at least 500gb. How to achieve that without touching the W10 partition at all (it's a lab environment with some crucial drivers & licences on it).

I already tried to delete the Unix partition and extend the W10 to the right and then install the Unix again at the end. However I always fail as I can't repair the grub after deleting debian - so I'm stuck in limbo.

Any good recipe how to do so? Ty!!

Comment: Do you have good backup? Then if you use Live installer to delete ext4 & swap (you may have to unmount it) and then use Windows to extend the NTFS does that not work? You are using the old BIOS/MBR configuration, so can only have 4 primary partitions. If your Windows install is so critical do you not have a full backup of it. Or keep old drive on shelf as backup. But once expanded you need larger backup drive.

Comment: TY. I have the "old" ssd + a raid1 for all systems. So the backup is fine. 
Actually what you wrote is what I did & described above I think. Wdym by "live installer"? Unix live disc? I did it via gparted live usb. Unfortunately grub had an error afterwards and I couldn't repair.

Comment: What error on grub? Is Windows fast start up off. Note that Windows keeps turning it back on and that may cause issues. Are you installing in BIOS/MBR mode. If newer system and you select UEFI install when booting live installer or creating live installer, it will fail as you do not have an ESP. You cannot really have Windows in BIOS and Ubuuntu in UEFI. After install & error, add Boot-Repair to live installer & run the Summary report. Copy & paste the pastebin link to the Boot-info summary report ( do not post report), do not run the auto fix.
 https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair